# How to sort a column in ascending order where the column contains varchar and numeric, using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actually my column is in varchar, and it has numeric and varchar type data, i just wanted to sort numeric first then varchar type.

I refered and got this:

```
 SELECT
 ...
ORDER BY
  CASE 
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(value) = 1 THEN CONVERT(INT, value) 
    ELSE 9999999 -- or something huge
  END,
  value
```

It works, but why we need to use `ELSE 9999999` here, instead what we can replace...?

Any solution for this...!

Comment: Just use `TRY_CAST(val AS INT)` or skip else part

Comment: Thanks lad2015....! But if i skip else numeric data ordered at last, I don't need like that.

Comment: By default `Order by value` returned  numeric first and then varchar type

Comment: @Hasan, My column is in varchar type, and it gives, "1,10, 11, 12 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9", how do i fix this...?

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
ORDER BY IIF(TRY_CAST(val AS INT) IS NULL, 1, 0),TRY_CAST(val AS INT);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=40528e326dcd865ee28350cd7067ba69)**

Comment: Thank you so much lad2015...! What is `TRY_CAST` here, it show me as not build-in-function here..

Comment: @Dennis `TRY_CAST()` will attempt to cast string as desired datatype. If it's an invalid one - it will return a `NULL`. The difference between `CAST()` and `TRY_CAST()` is that the first one will fail and the second will bring back `NULL` on invalid input value.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @Evaldas Buinauskas

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as an alternative solution.

```
SELECT
...
ORDER BY
  ISNUMERIC(value) DESC
  , CASE 
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(value) = 1 THEN CONVERT(INT, value) 
  END
  ,value
```